# Why is "there" a subject while "here" isn't?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

The question about "[the role of infinitive in this sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286047/the-role-of-infinitive-in-this-sentence/286050?noredirect=1#comment637935_286050)" prompted me to ask the following question.

English uses a "***dummy***" such as *it* and *there* to start a sentence when ***there*** is nothing else to start an extra-posed sentence in the linked question or a sentence starting with "there". Please read the comments below the answer.

I object to calling "there" *a subject of the sentence* in the following:

> There is a man at the door.

There is redundant as it could be rephrased to "A man is at the door/A man is there (pointing at the door)" as "at the door" indicates the place where a man physically *exist* at this moment. Here, "there" is a dummy which means nothing.

Another example:

> There was no snow yesterday.

In this sentence, there means nothing and just indicates the existence of "snow" yesterday.

Oxford Online Dictionary classifies this dummy "there" as an "[***adverb***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/there)"

> 3 (usually there is/are) Used to indicate the fact or existence of
>   something: ‘***there***’s a restaurant round the corner’

Let's say two people are engaged in a phone conversation:

> A: There was much snow yesterday in our town. Was there much snow?
>   B:
>   ***Here*** was not much (snow).

If "there" in the abvoe is a subject as a dummy, why is "here" not a subject?

Note: I read the linked [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200642/whats-the-subject-of-there-is-my-biscuit-and-how-about-there-is-one-biscu/200676?s=1|0.9257#200676) with an interest but it doesn't address why "here" cannot be a *dummy subject* like *dummy there*.

Comment: I don't get it. I can clearly add meanings to both here and there. Actually they make perfect matches to several other languages too, Turkish and Japanese being the 2 examples I can give. There: Asoko in Japanese and There: Orada in Turkish and is/are and was/were are time indicators and subject pronoun indicators. I read the other explanations for locator and dummy there but for me dummy there is not dummy at all.

Comment: @Grizzly Asoko in Japanese is a pronoun. There and here are adverbs (sometimes nouns). Big difference there. As I don't know anything about Turkish, I can't comment on it.

Comment: same in Turkish too but the dummy there, I can totally imagine it in my mind. For me it doesn't feel dummy at all. Nonetheless, interesting read.

Comment: A brief look in the google leads me to believe that the locative *there* and the dummy-subject *there* were both present in Old English.  I haven't put this in an answer because I don't know enough to evaluate the sources.  Given that Old English had a dummy-subject *there* but no dummy-subject *here*, it's no surprise that modern English is the same.  The question then becomes why would you expect a dummy-subject *here*?  Of course, this pushes the question back to Old English.

Comment: @deadrat Yes, I worried that it would be close-voted as primarily opinion- based when I posted it. There is no etymological explanation in the previous link and  your input will be much appreciated if you don't mind.

Comment: "Here" and "there" are used quite differently in A and B. The former is specifying a location, it's not a "dummy". It's only the fact that "there" can also be used to indicate a location that makes them feel similar. The distinction is clearer if you say "here, there was not much snow" (which sounds much more natural than your version)

Comment: @Rupe I understand you point. If I had used more natural version, this question would not work. My point is "there" is as much adverbial as "here". In other words, "here" is as as much dummy-subject-like as "there".

Comment: Yes that's what I took you to mean. Sorry but I think you're wrong. "Here" in this case is a straightforward locative adverb that clearly adds meaning that's not there otherwise. It's only the similarity of form between the 2 sentences and the fact that "here" is related to (another sense of) "there" that makes them seem at all similar. Compare with "In London (there) was not much snow". Would you say that "In London" is a dummy subject in that?

Comment: @Rathony I've put what I found in an answer that I hope it useful but hedged enough not to be misleading.

Comment: @Rathony You're welcome.  It's an interesting question, and I hope someone with a working knowledge of Old English chimes in if only to let us know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Here is an example of a sentence that uses "here".

Comment: @HotLicks Good one. I like that.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, but it isn't a Subject there though.

Comment: @Araucaria - How is "here" not the subject??

Comment: @HotLicks It's a case of Subject-dependent inversion, which happens a lot with BE.

Comment: @Araucaria - And you would make the same claim for "It is an example of a sentence"?

Comment: @Araucaria - I think if you study the references you will see that this is NOT an example of subject-dependent inversion.

Comment: @HotLicks Try the tests outlined in Bill's answer below. Have you *got* any references to say that *here* is a Subject in that sentence?

Comment: @HotLicks In "it is an example of a sentence" the sentence means "it = an example of a sentence". That is clearly not what your sentence means. It means "In this place is an example of a sentence", not "In this place = an example of a sentence". Try the tests outlined by Bill on that "It's an example, isn't it" versus *"Here's an example, isn't here".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t go along with that. Locative “there” is an adverb (some grammars call it a prep) rhyming with “dare” and meaning “in or at that place”. Dummy pronoun “there” on the other hand is pronounced unstressed with a reduced vowel and used to fill the syntactic subject position in existential clauses. So there is a difference in category, pronunciation and meaning.

Historically, dummy pronoun “there” derives from the locative “there”, but it has been bleached of its locative meaning and reanalysed as a pronoun.

The point is that the dummy pronoun “there” is without doubt the syntactic subject in an existential clause, no less than “it” is the subject in an extraposed construction. This can easily be proved:

1. “There” occupies the basic subject position before the verb, e.g. “**There was** a nurse present”.
2. In subject-auxiliary inversion constructions it occurs after the auxiliary, e.g. “**Was there** a nurse present?”
3. “There” occurs as subject in interrogative tags, e.g. “There was a nurse present, **wasn’t there**”?

Yes, the Oxford Online dictionary does indeed give existential “there” as an adverb, but it is wrong! As usual, it is just using ‘adverb’ as a classificatory dumping ground for any word that doesn’t easily fit into one of the other word categories. The examples above demonstrate without doubt that existential “there” is a pronoun. In any case, the function of subject can’t normally be realised by an adverb.

To complete the syntax, the subject of the non-existential construction becomes a displaced subject in the existential version:

[1] "Several windows were open".
[2] "There were several windows open".

In [2] “several windows” is analysed as a displaced subject (an internal complement of the verb), but it does correspond **semantically** to the subject in the non-existential counterpart [1].

Finally, you asked why "here" could not be the subject in:

"Here was not much snow".

"Here" is not a pronoun here, but an adverb (some call it a prep) so it can't possibly be subject. The syntactic subject in this example is "not much snow", and "here" is locative predicative complement. Think of it as "Not much snow was here". As further evidence, note that inversion would not be possible, *"Was here not much snow"?

Comment: Nice answer. Before I upvote, I've got a niggle (can't help it!), "Was here not much snow" is marginally grammatical to me. For example "Was here, not just the other day, his Lordship himself?" Not so felicitous with a light Subject as in your example. So I'm not sure you've rigorously shown that *here* is not the Subject yet. Saying that it's an adverb and therefore isn't a Subject is begging the question a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I would appreciate your input for the follow up [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286230/is-the-subject-there-flawed) and @Araucaria, your input will be much appreciated.

Comment: In which dialect of English are there multiple pronunciations for *there*??

Comment: @curiousdannii Yours for a start ;)

Comment: @Araucaria I'm sceptical about that.

Comment: @curiousdannii Try saying *there's* like a plurals form of the word *the* (put two "the"s in that title), Then stick it in a sentence like *thes nothing we can do*. Should sound ok ... What d'you think?

Comment: @Araucaria I don't know what you're trying to get me to say, but it's certainly not natural for me at least. *The* and *a* both have two pronunciations, but not *there* not in AusEng and not in any other dialects that I've heard.

Comment: @curiousdannii Haven't you heard RP or Gen Am on the TV?

Comment: @Araucaria of course. Maybe I just haven't noticed it, but I'm sure that I'd notice if there were two semantically distinct heteronyms of *there*. Wiktionary gave two pronunciations for UK and only one for US, but I think the diphthong/monophthong difference would be between accents, not within one accent.

Comment: @curiousdannii Certainly in RP (and most varieties of British English) the unstressed existential pronoun is homophonous with the definite article (unless followed by a vowel, when it has an /r/). The adverb/preposition like other adverbs has no weak form at all.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm surprised that Aust Englishes don't seem to have a weak form (I've been checking on youtube!) for existential *there* ...

Comment: @Araucaria Surprises all round then :)

Comment: Bill, the other problem is that *here* like other preposition phrases *can* of course function as Subject. For example *Here is better than there*, *Is here ok?* and so forth. So that rather pulls the rug from under your assertion that ""Here" is not a pronoun here, but an adverb (some call it a prep) so it can't possibly be subject" (Not my downvote btw, am waiting to upvote!)

Comment: I think we can say that *Was here not much snow*? is ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJohnstone Yes, I'd agree in general. However, what about the *here* can't function as a Subject thingie?

Comment: The OP was essentially asking if "here" can be an existential subject (he called it a dummy subject)

Comment: "Here" can also be a subject in something like "Here's me when I was six", where the personal pronoun is in the accusative case, indicating that "here" must be subject with the pronoun as predicative complement - rather like demonstrative "this". But the OP's point that "it doesn't address why "here" cannot be a dummy subject like dummy there" has I think been answered. Certainly, I was trying to focus on the existential aspect/dummy pronoun aspect, which I think was what the OP was really interested in.

Comment: Right, agreed :)  So your Predicative Complement point is correct and helpful, but the idea that it can't possibly be a subject  - *because* it's a preposition/adverb isn't helpful in the end, it would seem to seem ...

Comment: Why are you dwelling on this? I've already explained that in the OP's  example ("Here was not much snow") "here" is a locative complement, NOT the subject. It's just a simple case of inversion. The problem is that we now get into the realms of adverb vs prep, which normally brings howls of derision from the pro-adverb camp.Yes, PPs can be a subject, but relatively rarely, and in the OP's example, for the sake of clarity, it is best to think of "here" as being as a locative complement irrespective of whether its word category is an adverb or a preposition

Comment: Well, it's because the rest of your answer is based on evidence, but that line sticks out like a sore thumb and puts a downer on your excellent answer for any intelligent, reflective or observant reader, because it's clearly untrue. Whereas the rest of your post is excellent. It's not a side issue in your post because you make such a strong claim on the basis of it.

Answer (score 2):

A brief look in the google on the search string

> "dummy there" "Old English"

finds a few references like *[The Syntax of Spoken Indian English](https://books.google.com/books?id=3N_fJZn4yKAC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22dummy%20there%22%20%22old%20english%22&source=bl&ots=bJIwuLX_jD&sig=ekM7c3uAxsHLGvTSPusaXaLWOr0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAWoVChMIlv64wsOFyQIVBnkmCh0wAwWP#v=onepage&q=%22dummy%20there%22%20%22old%20english%22&f=false)*, which despite its title discusses the Old English origins of *there* as dummy subject.  The references are to primary sources, which I haven't (and am not qualified) to evaluate.

But if the Old English *þǣr*, (there) had usages as both a locative and a dummy subject, but *hēr* (here) didn't, then it's no surprise that modern English is the same.

Of course, this serves to push the question back to Old English.

Answer (score 1):

Some etymology might be useful:

#### there

- Indo-European pronoun stem: te, to
- proto-Germanic pronoun stem: þe, þa
- Gothic:  (þar)
- Old English: þær, thēr
- Old Saxon: thār
- Old Frisian: thĕr (Dutch: daar)
- Old High German: dăr (German: da, dar-)

#### here

- proto-Germanic pronoun stem: hi
- Gothic:  (hĕr)
- Old English: hĕr
- Old Saxon: hĕr
- Old Frisian: thĕr (Dutch: daar)
- Old High German: hĕr, hiar (German: hier)

In both of these (*there*, *here*) we have the common indo-European locative suffix *-r* or *-re*.

Compare *the* where the locative suffix is missing, although the Indo-European stem *to* is the same:

#### the

- Indo-European pronoun stem: so, to
- Sanskrit: sa, tad
- Gothic:  (sa),  (þata)
- Old English: se, ðæt
- Middle English: ther
- Old Saxon: thĕ, thie
- Old Frisian: thi
- Old High German: der (German: der)

*There* and *the* are related, *here* is not.

Answer (score 0):

"Here's some coffee."

"Here are the books you asked for earlier."

Try to rephrase this:

"There's something about the entire concept of cosmology that isn't quite honest."

"There" and "here" are equals, except "there" is more equal than "here" because it is used more frequently. Suppose you've organized a contest with fifty participants. The rules only allow one winner. Even if all of the participants are idiots, they're not equally stupid; nor are they equally fortunate. You're going to have your winner no matter what. (Look at politicians; look at business moguls. Like everyone else, you find yourself scratching your head now and then, saying "No ... He can't be THAT stupid." But he IS. That's because a contest, any contest, will always have a winner. No matter how poorly everyone in the league is playing, one team is going to win the championship at the end of the season. No matter how absurdly inept the current crop of established authors is, someone's always going to win the Nobel Prize. And so it is with "here" and "there." They are equals, but "here" is very obviously the winner.

As for the proverbial "it," there is a theory (or: here's a theory) that might appeal to your sense of humor:

Some say that it stands for that which shouldn't be named, some kind of supernatural force in charge of everything (not God: God is above it, He created "it"). Don't hold me to it, I don't remember where I read it, nor when.

As for "there" in the sense of "voila!" or "That's it! Don't touch anything, and don't breath until I've taken some pictures!" - well, that's just an interjection, isn't it? Well, maybe not. Maybe it's a variant of "Lo and behold," I don't know.

Comment: Had you restricted this to its first two lines I would have up-voted it.

Comment: @WS2: Do I look like a hundred dollar bill to you? I never expect to be liked by everyone.

Comment: Had you restricted this to its last three words I would have up-voted it.

Comment: Regardless of what kind of currency you look like, how about not exceeding your expectations for a change?  This doesn't begin to answer the question.  You can say "*There* was no snow yesterday" but not "*Here* was no snow yesterday."  The two words are not equals because we have there-insertion but no here-insertion.  Frequency of usage has nothing to do with it.  Consider deleting this answer.

Comment: @deadrat: I said they were equal. I didn't say they were interchangeable.

Comment: But there is no there there.