# Is the subject "there" flawed?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

This is a follow-up question to this [one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286178/why-is-there-a-subject-while-here-isnt?noredirect=1#comment638222_286178) and I understand the difference between "there" and "here".

I understand "there" functions differently from the adverb "here", but it leads to another question. It might sound too basic, but I believe it is relevant to why there could be some uncertainty in accepting *there* as a subject.

1. If you Google search "There is a dog in the house" and "There is my dog in the house", there is not a single hit for the latter, zero, nothing, nada while I get 738,000 hits for the former. You get 258,000 hits for "My dog is in the house".
2. If you Google search "There is a cat in the house" and "There is my cat in the house", still you get no hit for the latter and 358,000 hits for the former. You get 767,000 hits for "My cat is in the house".

You don't find any results for "There is my dog in his/her/our/their house", either.

Apparently, *there* doesn't seem to be used when determiner "my" (or other possessives) is used for a noun.

Another flaw, if you like, is a subject-verb agreement.

There sometimes takes a singular "be" for a "plural noun" that follows it. As @John Lawler pointed out in the [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200642/whats-the-subject-of-there-is-my-biscuit-and-how-about-there-is-one-biscu/200676#200676)

> There's one biscuit left ~ There's a unicorn in the garden ~ There's
>   someone here to see you. (One can say There is, but it's far commoner
>   to start a There-Insertion sentence with There's
>   -- even ***when the postposed subject is plural -- There's some people here to see you)***.

There are some people here to see you is much more broadly used as the below shows.

[image]

My question is:

1. Is the subject "there" as a "dummy subject" flawed as the above-mentioned points seem to suggest?
2. Using a singular verb "be" before a "plural" noun ungrammatical?
3. Why is there no usage of "there is my dog in the house"?

Note: I am reluctant to ask the third question and please disregard it if you consider it to be "too basic a question".

Thank you!

Comment: Uh, remember that no one would say "There is my dog."  It would be "There's my dog."

Comment: @HotLicks I just Googled it and found no hit for "There's my dog in the house."

Comment: Well, no one's gonna say that either.  "There's a dog in my house" gets a bunch of hits.

Comment: And you don't get hits for "there is some people" because that's generally considered to be bad syntax.

Comment: @HotLicks That's why I put the "note". But, can it be grammatically explained without saying that's the way it is?

Comment: Actually, "There's my dog, in the house" (with a comma) might be said in an exasperated voice after searching through the woods fruitlessly.

Comment: And while the Lawler quote quote "There's some people here to see you" definitely occurs (whether syntactically correct or not), it's much more idiomatic to say "There are some people here to see you".

Comment: [_There_-Insertion](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=there-insertion) transforms a subject noun phrase with _be_ into a predicate NP. However, the rule can only apply to **indefinite** predicate noun phrases, like _a unicorn_ or _some people_. What it all means, @Rathony, is that the grammatical concept of "subject" is useful for some things, but in fact it's made up of a number of usually overlapping features, which can get separated by one process or another. When that happens, as here, you get ambivalent test results, and ambivalent "feelings" about what the `Subject` should really be.

Comment: Why is this a flaw? It may be a non-intuitive aspect of English grammar, but I see no reason to call it a flaw.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for your comment. Which word would you recommend to use if I used it to mean it doesn't function perfectly as a subject.

Comment: @Rathony I'll give you an answer when I get a chance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I can't see any reason to doubt its function as subject in existential constructions. I wouldn't call its function 'dummy subject', though, as that implies it is not the syntactic subject, which it clearly is.
2. Existential *there* is an unusual subject; it has no inherent number, but takes on the number of the displaced subject:

*There were some keys near the safe*. (plural with *were*)

*There was a nurse present*. (singular with *was*)

It’s comparable to the relative pronouns *which* and *who*, which take on the number of their antecedent (*the guys who were talking* vs *the guy who was talking*). However, in informal style, especially in present tense declaratives with **reduced *is***, many speakers treat *there* as always singular: they say *There’s a few problems* instead  of *There are a few problems*. Prescriptivists disapprove, but the usage is too well established to be treated as an occasional slip.

3. There is a strong tendency for the displaced NP to be indefinite, as in *There is a dog in the house*, but *my dog* is a definite NP in *There's my dog in the house*, which is why it is ungrammatical (at least in most dialects). However, definite NPs are admissible provided they represent addressee-new information, as in:

A. *I can't imagine what I'm going to make for dinner tonight*.

B. *Well, there's that leftover meatloaf*.