# Is it Ok to place a prepositional phrase before 'there is/are'?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion, there-is

> In the center of the room there is a column.

vs.

> There is a column in the center of the room.

*If both are* grammatical, is there a preferable way? Does context or style influence the choice?

--

I've read 5 pages of there is/are questions and failed to find this simple one. Most of the questions concern choosing singular or plural, correct positions of negation, adverbs, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help! I will uncheck your answer now and get back to it in a couple of days, that sounds quite wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There* is usually called *dummy pronoun* and according to the answer posted by @BillJ in the question, [Why is “there” a subject while “here” isn't?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286178/why-is-there-a-subject-while-here-isnt/286206#286206):

> To complete the syntax, the subject of the non-existential
>   construction becomes a displaced subject in the existential version:
>
> [1] "Several windows were open". [2] "There were several windows
>   open".
>
> In [2] “several windows” is analysed as a displaced subject (an
>   internal complement of the verb), but it does correspond semantically
>   to the subject in the non-existential counterpart [1].

The example sentence "In the center of the room there is a column." has the same meaning as "There is a column in the center of the room." and the prepositional phrase (PP) *in the center of the room* has been **fronted** to emphasize the location of the column. In this case, using *there* is optional because the PP already indicates the place where the column is. In other words, both

> In the center of the room **was there a column**. (There was a column in the center of the room.)

(You need to note that the word order of the verb *was* and the subject *there* is changed. Also, there are cases where the change doesn't occur.)

> In the center of the room was a column. (A column was in the center of the room.)

are grammatically valid. The main purpose of [**fronting**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/fronting) is to emphasize the fronted word or phrase.

> Some elements like adjuncts or complements do not typically belong at the beginning of a clause. When we want to focus on them, we bring them to the front or beginning of the clause. We often find this in written literary or formal contexts.

[Cambridge Dictionary Grammar]

Comment: Why do the verb and the Subject invert in your example?

Comment: I don't think other answers can best this one. Thanks again.

Comment: @NoxNoctis Glad it helped! Some grammar books or grammarians will tell you the subject-verb inversion will only occur when there is a Negative Polarity Item (NPI), but I have seen many sentences where it occurs when a prepositional phrase is fronted. Please read this link for your further study. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80644/subject-auxiliary-inversions-not-associated-with-questions and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they. I don't see any reason why the bolded part is impossible. That's my opinion.