# "Here", "there", and "where"

Tags: etymology, orthography, morphology

Are "here", "there", and "where" morphological cognates, or just an orthographic coincidence?

Comment: The *h/th/wh-* set also combine with *-ither* and *-ence* not just with *-ere*, so yes, it’s more than coincidence.

Comment: It's part of a very old paradigm. In fact, it's such a prototype that I made [a puzzle out of it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.pdf) to show students what paradigms are and how to construct them. (though I notice there's a mistake in the ablative plural in the example; ah, well :-)

Comment: 66% duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/286292/191178

Comment: It's actually the common " -here" that I was wondering about, because of the semantic connection that "there", "where" and "here" all refer to location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this is shown in many Indo-Aryan and Dravidian languages, I would not call this phenomenon an 'orthographic coincidence'.
Example, in  Sanskrit: 
'atra'- here 
'tatra'- there 
'kutra'- where

Answer (score 0):

"here", "there", and "where" are indeed morphological cognates because they form the structure of the sentence. Whenever these are used they are either a result of query whose base are these or either the answer of query. So it is more than just a orthographic co-incidence since "here", "there", and "where" form the basic structure and of the sentence.