# 'It is adj to V' 's to -infinitive

Tags: infinitives

It is said that he was murdered.
/It is nice to meet someone.
/She is difficult to persuade.

About 'to meet someone'. Do Americans read it the same as 'that he was murdered', which is a Real Subject, or as 'to persuade', which is a complement?

Comment: What do you mean by "Real Subject"?

Comment: 'It' in the first sentence is not actually the real subject. The real subject, 'he was murdered' has been moved to the back to avoid a long subject existing in the usual position.

Comment: This is not a single question. Does this answer your (tough-movement) question? [To infinitive used after adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277710/to-infinitive-used-after-adjective)

Comment: @Kim Hui-jeong As BillJ indicates, we can't just use terminology we might be familiar with here and assume (1) OP will be cognisant of it / (2) it's the standard (definitive) terminology / or even (3) it's the most widely accepted terminology. Different grammars might even reject rather than precise the term. A specifying definition and a citation are essential.

Comment: Syntactically, "it" is a dummy element  serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of it but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP. The extraposed version is far more likely than the basic version "To meet someone is nice".